# Getting an error discriminating a union type ("property not found in object type")

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I am having a hard time describing the type of a function argument which is either a success or an error api response. Here is a simple puzzling example of the problem (reproduced in TryFlow at [this address](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBTAHgBzgJwBcxCBPHDMAUX3wICUMBnPAOycoF4wBvVMDLQIAuXvzBgAtsyYBDAOYZRTQvgCWreQBp+AX1T7MuAsTIUwAZQCuAYxszGLOOy5iScANYZWovhLBqACbKqhraegboUFasNoRqzmDO1gBGkmqEABT4zGwcotZ2DrnOHGAAPtRC+I55GACUbgFQYNklLgB0gnT4jX7+ABayrIEwGDQ9bU4u9QDc4roCMGX9EkMjY4X2TExTdXMLkajRsfGJ66Pj1XulSlU9tbd94jalcGMd8PI3nd0EHdIdgoGvNDCc4glWGALptbNtdjlpvlLHDikiGk1Xux3hhPnBvoi6h1CJ5vB0ggd9EA))

The function can take either a success response object or an error response object:

```
export type ErrorResponse = {
 error: {
   message: string,
 }
}

export type SuccessResponse = {
 token: {
   id: string,
 }
}
```

it should then decide which kind of response it is and pass the response to either `handleSuccess` or `handleError` functions:

```
function onSubmit(response: SuccessResponse | ErrorResponse) {
  if (response.error) {
    handleError(response);
  } else {
    handleSuccess(response);
  }
}

function handleError(response: ErrorResponse) {
  console.log(response.error.message);
}

function handleSuccess(response: SuccessResponse) {
  console.log(response.token.id);
}
```

The problem is, Flow is giving an error:

```
23: function handleError(response: ErrorResponse) {
                                   ^ property `error`. Property not found in
17:     handleError(response);
                    ^ object type
```

The error goes away if instead of the union type (`SuccessResponse | ErrorResponse`) I type the response object as an intersection type (`SuccessResponse & ErrorResponse`), but that can't be right — I am not passing into the `onSubmit` function an object that has **all** properties of both types, but an argument that can be **either** of the two types.

Could you please explain what I am doing wrong and advise on how to fix this typing error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you get is that Flow doesn't know if `SuccessResponse` has a possible extra `error` param.

To tell Flow that it doesn't, you can make [exact Object types](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-exact-object-types):

```js
export type ErrorResponse = {|
  error: {
    message: string,
  },
|}

export type SuccessResponse = {|
  token: {
    id: string,
  },
|}
```

Answer (score 0):

To access a member that is not common to all types in a union, you have to give flow a way to see which type it's dealing with.  I understand that you're trying to use the truthiness of `error` to determine the specific type, but flow does not understand this.

The pattern flow uses for this situation is called "disjoint unions".  It is described here: https://flow.org/en/docs/types/unions/

I'm not an expert on flow, but it seems one solution would be to modify your type definition for `SuccessResponse` as follows:

```
export type SuccessResponse = {
  error: typeof undefined,
  token: {
    id: string,
  }
}
```